# Are two nice equidimensional varieties with the same Euler characteristic fibers of a flat morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, flatness

I'm very amused by the ability of Euler characteristic to withstand any deformation.
I would be very impressed if one had a geometric analogue of homotopy (much rougher) that captured all pairs with the same Euler characteristic.

Recently I saw an interesting theorem that might offer such a solution at least in the context of algebraic geometry; under good conditions (everything projective etc) if $X \to Y$ is flat, then the fibers have the same Euler characteristic (of the structure sheaf).

My question is thus if under good conditions, if $X,Y$ are equidimensional with the same euler characteristic there is a flat map connecting them; a 'very rough deformation' if you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for example, a $K3$ surface and an elliptic surface have the same Eular characteristic $\chi(\mathcal{O})$ and dimension, but they can't fit in a flat family. (For smooth varieties to fit in a flat family, they are deformation equivalent, so they have to be diffeomorphic.)

For a given projective family $X\to T$, it is flat if and only if the Hilbert polynomials on the fibers are constant. So a refined question to ask is probably

Question: If two polarized projective varieties $X,Y$ have the Hilbert polynomial, is there a flat family connecting $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: hmm, I don't want to limit to smooth flat maps because of the problem you state; so that I can connect nonsingular hyperbolas to a singular one

Comment: @Andy The morphism $f: X\to T$ doesn't has to be smooth: If $f$ is flat and the two fibers are smooth, then one can restrict to an open $T'\subseteq T$ where the restricted $X'\to T'$ is smooth.

Comment: @Andy For curves, it is a matter of components of Hilbert schemes. To my knowledge, $H_{d,g,r}$, the Hilbert scheme of degree $d$, genus $g$ curves in $\mathbb P^r$ has more than one components in general. So the question is when are these two curves lie in the same component of the Hilbert scheme.

Comment: omg damn you complex numbers, you're saying that codimension one in complex numbers is still connected, fair enough.